# Убрать пустое пространство между ссылками

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Не как не получается убрать расстояние между ссылками.

```css
.menu {
 border-left: 28px solid green;
 border-right: 28px solid green;
 text-align: center;
 /*background-color: green;*/
}

.menu a {
 background-color: green;
 padding: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.menu a:hover {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
 <div class="menu">
  <a href="/">Главная</a>
  <a href="/">О компании</a>
  <a href="/">Продукция</a>
  <a href="/">Где купить</a>
  <a href="/">Калькулятор</a>
  <a href="/">Документация</a>
  <a href="/">Новости</a>
  <a href="/">Контакты</a>
 </div>
```

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Добавьте в `.menu a` свойство `float: left;`

Comment: parent - font-size: 0; child - font-size: xx px;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тут вообще Господа верстальщики какие то советы надовали кх,кх в общем  любой список должен быть оформлен согласно семантической ценности , а это `ul>li>a` 
это скрин того что получится в этом случае 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**ниже пример в сниппете**

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.menu {
 border-left: 28px solid red;
 border-right: 28px solid red;
 text-align: center;
}
.menu li{
  list-style:none;
  display:inline-block;
  height:40px;
  background:green;
  line-height:40px;
  padding:0 10px;
}
.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
.menu li:hover{
  background:darkgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
  <li><a href="/">Главная</a>
  <li><a href="/">О компании</a>
  <li><a href="/">Продукция</a>
  <li><a href="/">Где купить</a>
  <li><a href="/">Калькулятор</a>
  <li><a href="/">Документация</a>
  <li><a href="/">Новости</a>
  <li><a href="/">Контакты</a>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

**Но всё же если так требуется сделать меню без маркированного списка то вот так**
пример того что получится
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
   *{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.menu{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
  background:#fff;
  border-left:20px solid darkgreen;
  border-right:20px solid darkgreen;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
menu{
  display:table;
  margin:auto;
  height:50px;
  line-height:50px;
  background:#FFF;
}
menu a{
  padding:17px 10px;
  background:lightgreen;
}
menu a:hover{
  background:darkgreen;
  color:#fefefe;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<menu>
  <a href="">Главная</a>
  <a href="">Гостевая</a>
  <a href="">Форум</a>
  <a href="">Блог</a>
  <a href="">Обо всё</a>
  <a href="">Примеры</a>
  <a href="">Задачи</a>
  <a href="">О нас</a>
</menu>
</div>
```

А [этот пример на codepen](http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/YWRaYJ?editors=110) вообще хоть и не по теме вопроса но супер решение + адаптивное

Answer (score 2):

Добавлю еще один способ. Нужно закомментировать пространственно между ссылками, т.к. браузеры считают это интервалом между словами. Так же можно просто расположить теги в коде подряд, одной строкой, без промежутков и перевода строки.

```css
.menu {
 border-left: 28px solid green;
 border-right: 28px solid green;
 text-align: center;
 /*background-color: green;*/
}

.menu a {
 background-color: green;
 padding: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.menu a:hover {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
 <a href="/">Главная</a><!--
 --><a href="/">О компании</a><!--
 --><a href="/">Продукция</a><!--
 --><a href="/">Где купить</a><!--
 --><a href="/">Калькулятор</a><!--
 --><a href="/">Документация</a><!--
 --><a href="/">Новости</a><!--
 --><a href="/">Контакты</a>
</div>
```

Comment: про закоментирования пространства не знал + с меня

Answer (score 1):

```css
.menu {
 border-left: 28px solid green;
 border-right: 28px solid green;
 text-align: center;
 /*background-color: green;*/
}

.menu a {
 background-color: green;
 padding: 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: -3px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 border-left: 1px solid #000;
 border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

.menu a:hover {
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="/">Главная</a>
  <a href="/">О компании</a>
  <a href="/">Продукция</a>
  <a href="/">Где купить</a>
  <a href="/">Калькулятор</a>
  <a href="/">Документация</a>
  <a href="/">Новости</a>
  <a href="/">Контакты</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: минусовой margin это топорное решение

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="menu">
        <a href="/">Главная</a><a href="/">О компании</a><a href="/">Продукция</a><a href="/">Где купить</a><a href="/">Калькулятор</a><a href="/">Документация</a><a href="/">Новости</a><a href="/">Контакты</a>
    </div>
```

Както так, суть в том что между ними есть символ табуляции, которые браузер делает пробелами.

а `display: inline-block;` еще и добавляет перед каждым последующим за первым елементом по 4 пиксела, которые можно убрать с помощью `margin-left:-4px`

Answer (score -4):

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
  <a href="/">Главная
  <a href="/">О компании
  <a href="/">Продукция
  <a href="/">Где купить
  <a href="/">Калькулятор
  <a href="/">Документация
  <a href="/">Новости
  <a href="/">Контакты
 </div>
```

на самом деле решений много, вот одно из рабочих, удаляем закрывающие теги - html5 позволяет так сделать

Comment: а ошибки синтаксиса мы как уберем?